# Embedding MANY pictures in a single GitHub page

Tags: html, image, github, server, github-pages

I want to embed ~20 jpg pictures to a single Github page. The total size of pictures is over 120M, so I converted them to .webp files before uploading them to the server.

However, later I found that webp format is not supported by IE and Safari (yet), and my target users tend to use Safari on their iPhones. As a quick fix, I replaced all webpage files with the original jpg files in my repo, which means I uploaded ~120M pictures to the server.

Uploading so much non-code data to Github's server seems somewhat immoral to me, and having to wait a ~120M webpage to load sounds awful to the users. How can I handle this situation more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I handle this situation more elegantly?

Simply upload them to an external picture referential (not a Git repo server), and reference their full url in your page.
That will be easier than trying to store everything in a Git repo.

You also have [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), but that is for Git repo users will checkout your repo, not for user reading the content of a GitHub page.